# Get binary file data sent from postman?

Tags: node.js, postman

I am Trying to get data which is sent from binary option from postman in nodejs but when i print req.body it returns blank object. 
can any one tell me how do i get that data?

[image]

**code:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.text()); // This will parse your file

app.post('/data/UploadLogsToServer', async (req, res) => {
   res.status(200).send(req.body)
});

const server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

**Foo.txt file**

```
StoreApiCode=retailgraph&Content={"Type": "INFO ","TimeStamp":"2018-10-10 12:05:16.881","IP":"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a","MacId":"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4","OS":"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language","Method":"SyncData","LineNo":527,"Message":"SyncData: Billing Software SyncData() called"}
{"Type": "INFO ","TimeStamp":"2018-10-10 12:05:17.060","IP":"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a","MacId":"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4","OS":"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language","Method":"SyncData","LineNo":38,"Message":"SyncData: Start"}
{"Type": "INFO ","TimeStamp":"2018-10-10 12:05:17.111","IP":"2001:0:9d38:90d7:804:3589:8a3c:e43a","MacId":"84:7B:EB:3F:65:A4","OS":"Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language","Method":"SyncData","LineNo":44,"Message":"SyncData: LocalConnectionString = Data Source=PARAM\\MSSQL2K8r2;Initial Catalog=HQPharma;User ID=sa;Password=developer;"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postman, make sure your header has `Content-Type` = `application/octet-stream`. Then in your `app.post` definition, read the data in chunks. For example, below it returns a simple JSON response, but at least the server sees the data. It looks like your version doesn't:

```
    var data = '';
    app.post('/data/UploadLogsToServer',function(req, res) {

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      console.log(data);
    });

    var responseJson = {
      "message": "success!!!"
    };

    return res.status(200).send(responseJson);
  });
```

Comment: The 'end' event signals the end of reading the data. Inside the req.on('end', handler, you have all the data. Do whatever you need to do next, in that handler.